# magento2 - Data migration: missing configurable attributes after migration from 1.9.4.2

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product, data-migration-tool, configurable-product-options

After completing a data-migration trying to exclude the import of products I can no longer complete the saving of a configurable product and the following window is shown

[image: configurable modal]

I have a dump of the db created before migrating (with all configurable products ok), which table can I look at to try to solve the problem? thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think but i am not sure this problem is not assigned attributes in particular stock But you tried this solutions

Your attribute include after migration but you are not set the attribute in your store likes.So goes the following path and set your attributes store wise

> Stores > Attribute Sets > Select your attribute set > And Add the your attributes.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I solved it

Answer (score 0):

You should enter your store then select **the attribute set**. Next, find all the attributes that **create config product** and drag them to the attribute set you are using.