# How to get the data of custom attribute in magento 2 after migration

Tags: magento2, migration

I have a few doubts about migration.

If I migrate m1 data to m2 what happens to my m1 custom attribute.

I know that its data migration to Magento 2.

Now how can we link that data to Magento 2 custom attribute? or does it automatically generate the attribute in Magento 2?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/305337/magento2-data-migration-missing-configurable-attributes-after-migration-from/305353#305353 this link similar or not ???

Comment: what about those custom features which class do not map?

Comment: i don't understand you above comment ???

Comment: sometimes we get an error of class not maped. for that i usually delete the class or ignore how can we resolve the issue to worked it properly

Comment: eav_attribute.backend_model

Comment: this file `map.xml` i think you missed ignore some class . so this error

Comment: send your error ???

Comment: add this code your `map-eav.xml` file <ignore>
   <field>eav_attribute.backend_model</field>
</ignore>

Comment: i mean if we ignore class how will our that functionality work on magento 2

Comment: I have experienced these error on my last migration, My migration was successful but it left some doubts So I am trying to clear it

Comment: you ignore class no change any  functionality and work perfect ...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311305/magento2-issue-with-additional-dropdown-option-in-checkout

Comment: @MohitPatel please check the above link  I am implementing similar functionality. How are u saving the drop-down value? actually I want  Radio button

Comment: what's problem explain more .i think add new question full explanation.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311685/how-to-add-custom-block-field-data-in-db-from-shipping-method-page-in-magento-2

Comment: @MohitPatel here is the question that was posted 4 days ago

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import custom attributes from Magento 1 to Magento 2, you need to find a Magento migration expert to helps you do it.

Basically, you can directly import them to Magento 2 without any issues, however, if the custom attribute is created from the third module, you need to let the support team check it.

Comment: I want to do it myself. I already migrated m1 data to m2. There were few doubts I want to clear them. If u give me little bit guide ill appreciate that.

Comment: @MustafaAli, You can use the file 'map-eav.xml.dist' to migrate the attribute to Magento 2 by using the automated data-migration-tool. Or you need to import them manually.